# changing width and height to percentage in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, drupal, slideshow

i am using jquery slideshow.I have to change the width and height to pecentage value.

jquerytransitions.js contains the below code

```
$.fn.jqFancyTransitions.defaults = {    
        width: 682, // width of panel
        height: 268, // height of panel
        strips: 10, // number of strips
        delay: 5000, // delay between images in ms
        stripDelay: 50, // delay beetwen strips in ms
        titleOpacity: 0.7, // opacity of title
        titleSpeed: 1000, // speed of title appereance in ms
        position: 'alternate', // top, bottom, alternate, curtain
        direction: 'fountainAlternate', // left, right, alternate, random, fountain, fountainAlternate
        effect: '', // curtain, zipper, wave
        navigation: false, // prev next and buttons
        links : false // show images as links       
    };

})(jQuery);
```

i have to chnge the width and height to percentage..is it possible?

Comment: I dont think you can - if you look at the source for the plugin you will see that the developer adds `px` to the width/height param you pass ... you would need to either modify the source or set the width after using `.width()` and `.height()`

Comment: how can i do that? i have to change it to percentage

Comment: Modify the source code or change it after

Comment: To modify the source code download the code and modify it - you will need to find the section that converts the param to a number (`parseInt`) and the actual setup of the width and change to your percentage code ... to change post init then use either [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) or [.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) and [.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to replace the  width: 682, height: 268 with

```
width : screen.width * (47.45/100),
height: screen.height * (29.8/100),
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is manual calculation:

```
var percentage = 25; //Your desired percentage
daddyWidth = $('#daddyElelement').width();
finalWidth = daddyWidth*percentage/100;
```

the make your script take more options by adding more elements to the "parameters array" and at the end you can put those instead of the number of pixles

```
width: finalWidth , // width of panel
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the width and height to be relative to to browser window, use :

```
...
width : window.innerWidth * (percentage/100),
height: window.innerHeight * (percentage/100),
...
```

Or if you want it relative to any other element :

```
...
width : element.offsetWidth * (percentage/100),
height: element.offsetHeight * (percentage/100),
...
```

Comment: i tried this.   width:window.innerWidth * (48.25/100),  height:window.innerHeight * (38/100),  but appears differently in different systems